# How to get Mac Application Folder in Java

Tags: java, macos, path

In Windows to get the Programs folder I used this method: [Java - get "program files" path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851359/java-get-program-files-path)

is there a method to get the path to the Mac OSX Application folder from Java?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526435/executing-app-folder-from-java) what you want?

Comment: no I want the exact path of the Application Directory on OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X, you can use the known subdirectories of `user.home` cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14233171/230513).
If you use [*Java Web Start*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), you can offer to create a shortcut, which appears as a regular application.